# Measure how different are two groups in their answering on 25 ordinal variables

Tags: group-differences, distance, similarities

The research context:

I'm interested in usage frequency of special interest websites and its predictors.

I asked individuals (n=1000) for the usage of 25 different websites in 25 items in a survey (one item for each website). The items had a 5-point, ordinal scale ("How often have you visited website XYZ in the last six month? daily; at least once in a week, but not daily; at least once in month, but less often than once in a week; etc.).

For theoretical reasons, I assumed that there are differences between males and females in the usage of these websites. To check this, I plotted profile lines with medians of usage frequencies per group. Unsurprisingly, these lines showed clear differences in the website usage between males and females.

Given substantive considerations, the plotted lines were justification enough for me to run all subsequent analyses (cluster analysis and later multinominal logistic regression with other demographics) separately for both gender groups. That went well! However, for the paper I would now like to underpin my qualitative decision with a statistic that quantifies the difference between the two gender groups.

My question:

I'm looking for a measure that describes differences in answering patterns of two groups on 25 ordinal-scaled items that represent usage of 25 websites. Although, the items are scaled in the same way, I can not build an index as website usage is multi-dimensional in my case. I also don't want to run 25 regressions regressing frequency of usage of each of the 25 websites on gender. I rather look for a measure that quantifies how both groups would have needed to answer in order to have a similar usage of the websites. (Or something along these lines.)

So far, I have looked into inter-coder reliability measures, reasoning that I might take the two different groups as coders and there answers as coding decisions. I also had a first look into indices of segregation. However, I have the feeling that I'm looking into problem that represents a more common and proto-typical statistical problem, so that there will more general methods to approach it.

Your help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: you can represent the data as a contingency table, and then use a chisquare test.

Comment: thanks. (1) how would you aggregate the 25 chisquare test into one statistic? would you report a ratio, something like "17 of the 25 tests showed significant differences"?

Comment: (2) do you see a technique that could be superior to a chisquare test in a situation with high skew in some variables (some website are not used at all by males)?

Comment: (3) A last additional information: The sample is a convenient, non-probability sample.